# PhoneGap Android Barcode Scan UI modification

Tags: android, user-interface, cordova, barcode, zxing

Im currently using the Barcode Scanner from the open source library Zxing in my android project. The problem Im facing is concerning the scanning UI

When I launch the Scan window, it occupies the entire screen and Im not sure how to customize it - I would like to add a HTML back button in case the customer wants to scan or even better add the menu bar to be consistent with all other pages on my app ?

How do I add basic HTML elements in the scanning window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just calling BarcodeScanner via an intent you have no control. However if you are embedding the Java code from the BarcodeScanner app in your app you have all the java code and xml resources available and can edit them how you like. It will all be Java and native Android resource stuff though.. not html.

If you are embedding the layout is

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/res/layout/capture.xml

and the activity that does the scanning you want to edit is

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java

If you add a button in the layout and call finish in the OnClickListener you set up in the activity it would be a back as you desire..

Comment: Yeah im embedding the entire scanner library. Im super new on both the android/iphone app development scene - Hence the choice of phonegap to turn my webapp into Pseudo native apps...Would appreciate a lot if you could tell me which files exactly would I need to tinker with - all i need to do is add a back button ?

Comment: Hey Manfred: thanks a lot for the links ! I'm still struggling to figure out how to set a button in there and link it back to the index.html file. If you happen to know how to go about doing it from the top of your head, Would definitely be much appreciated :-)

Comment: No idea about PhoneGap... sorry .. you could probably do a button that calls finish() on the capture activity.. that would basically be a back()

Comment: Thanks I setup the button and the onclicklistener as you noted and it worked! Now i need to figure out how to place the button properly at the bottom of the window :-)

Comment: Any idea how I can align the button at the bottom of the screen ? I cant seem to master the layouts in Android..for the moment I added this to the button tag (android:layout_gravity="bottom") and it aligns it horizontally on the top. But i would want it ideally in the bottom of the screen. Thanks for your help

Comment: Shankar can you please guide me I am also doing the same thing but java does not work for me if I add all oncreate code under button onClick event. Please help me how to do this