# zxing barcode scanner in a fixed div in phonegap android app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, zxing

I have added zxing barcode scanner plugin successfully in my android phonegap app here is js code where on page show I am able to see barcode scanner screen.

```
  $('#scanpage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    //navigator.notification.alert("Search page");

    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result) {
        //navigator.notification.alert("We got a barcode\n" +   "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +"Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            //    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
         }, function(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }); 

});
```

here is html5 page code

```
div id="scanpage" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" class="pageheader">

<div class="height30" style="padding-right:2%;">
 <div class="back" style="margin-right:2%;"><a href="#homepage">Back</a></div>
<div class="logo2" ><a href="#"  ><img src="images/scan.png" style="padding-top:12px;" alt="Scan Code" /></a>
</div>
 </div>
 </div> 

<div data-role="content"  class="wrapper" style="width:100%">


 <div style="background-color:#000000;" >
 <div style="height:400px;" id="scanarea"></div>


 <input name="" type="button" class="button" value="Focus and Scan" data-role="none"   />

  </div><!-- inner div-->


</div>  
   </div> <!-- end SCAN PAGE -->
```

BUT how it works, when I open the page firstly load html but in second whole screen is covered with bar-code scanner window I want to fix this scan area in a DIV 'scanarea' . But don't know how to fix it in certain div area and on button click scanning will perform and read the barcode.

scan window
[image]

html page
[image]

need to show like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The barcode scanning screen is implemented as Android activity which hides PhoneGap's web view completely. If you want to customize this screen, you may want to change its [layout file](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/BarcodeScanner/LibraryProject/res/layout/capture.xml) somehow.

I assume that your button "Focus and scan" should trigger a manual scan (the default is to recognize the first barcode, I think) – therefore you may have to change the [activity implementation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/BarcodeScanner/LibraryProject/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java) to include a handler for that button.

See also [Simon Mac Donald's blog](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.de/) (he seems to be developing the barcode scanning plugin on Android) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9420741/245706) (which is exactly what I wrote above, snap :P).

Comment: let me check it. Thank you so much

Comment: Could you please help in handling java for scanning here is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627100/perform-scanning-manually-on-button-click-for-barcodesacnner-plugin-android-in-p